# python code to run command for each ip in the list and exit upon string match

Tags: python

I have following code:

```
import paramiko
import re

router_ip = "10.10.10.10"
router_username = "admin"
router_password = "admin"

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

# Load SSH host keys.
ssh.load_system_host_keys()
# Add SSH host key automatically if needed.
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
# Connect to router using username/password authentication.
ssh.connect(router_ip,
            username=router_username,
            password=router_password,
            look_for_keys=False)

# Run command.
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(
    "show l2route evpn mac-ip all | i HMM")
output = ssh_stdout.readlines()
output1 = " ".join(output)
ip_list = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', output1)

print(output1)
print(ip_list)

#ssh.close()
```

I have to run command "show bgp l2vpn evpn <IP_in_ip_list> vrf Tenant-1" command where "<IP_in_ip_list>" is each item (i.e. ip) in the list "ip_list" and if any output has string "VNI" than exit, stop running any command and print "match found, stop here". how to do this? It seems i will have to use for loop but I am not clear with how to do it.

please help. I am new to python.

Answer (score 0):

when you got a list of IPs here

```py
ip_list = re.findall(r'[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}', output1)
```

run this

```py
for ip in ip_list:
    ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(f"show bgp l2vpn evpn {ip} vrf Tenant-1")

    output = ssh_stdout.readlines()
    output1 = " ".join(output)
    if "VNI" in output1:
        print("match found, stop here")
        exit(0)
```